# Spark 1.5.2: Extract values from WrappedArray

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a `WrappedArray` with the following output that I want to extract values from:

```
val x = df.select("field1").head().get(0)
println(x)
```

It produces the following output:

```
WrappedArray([false,/tmp,2])
```

How do I extract the values from the Array?

Comment: Could you either [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or explain why it doesn't work for you so it can be improved? You also have quite a few  other questions with answers just asking for being accepted. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you want to do with them. You can extract individual items in the array:

```
df.select($"field1".getItem(0)).head().get(0)
```

You can `explode` the DF:

```
case class ArrayValue(value: String)
df.explode($"field1") {
  case Row(field: Seq[String]) => field.map(ArrayValue(_))
}.show
```

Comment: @Neel Could you either accept the answer or explain why it doesn't work for you so it can be improved? Thanks !